# How to create a secure web service?

Tags: php, web-services, wcf

I have a few web services in my server. They are basically php scripts which accept takes a few parameters, does processing and shows an output in json format. The things is currently the web services have no security. Which means if someone had the url and service name (php name) they could also call the service.

Now I want the web service to be called by mobile app, web app and desktop application. What sort of basic security should I put so that a person with url and service name cannot exploit it.
The preferred option would be one where changes in server is minimal/not required and only modifications can be made in the web service.

Anyway please suggest me what should I do. Someone suggested token system but I don't know what it is and how it works. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into any authentication service like https://oauth.net/? It has some handy APIs you can use :)

Comment: Oauth,net does add security to web service but I was unable to understand what scenario is suitable here.

Comment: There are a lot of different factors involved in this question. Who is making these apps? How are you going to manage accounts? Do you need to enforce rate limiting? What happens if you get DDoS'd? You may want to look at something like AWS API Gateway which can sit in front of your API: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

Comment: Actually I just need basic level of security right now to ensure a person who has a url of my web service cannot call it. I do not have a IT team so I need to get work done through a freelancer. Thats why i said basic level of security only. Should I just protect it with a passcode?

Comment: Good luck on this retrofitting security is never a good idea. However like the people mention look at OAuth etc.

Comment: I am trying to implement token system through OAuth. Basically if user verification is successful a token will be generated and that will be used through the application.